# Getting crazy over this loop :/

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I'm having troubles to fig out what's wrong with this logic. First loop is OK, and it prints pileOfNeg's elements correctly. On the other hand, second loop is throwing `"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException"`. Any suggestions?

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Arrays {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] array = {22, 53, -12, 0, 23, 145, -14, -85, 63, 42, 0, -599, -17};
        Arrays.sort(array);

        //Ok, there is 5 neg elements, print 'em out  
        int[] pileOfNeg = new int[array.length - 8]; 
        for (int n = 0; n < array.length; n++) {
            if (array[n] < 0) {
                pileOfNeg[n] = array[n];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("pileOfNeg: " + Arrays.toString(pileOfNeg));

    //Good, now print pos ones, forget zeroes 
    int[] pileOfPos = new int[array.length - 7];
    for (int p = 0; p < array.length; p++) {
        if (array[p] > 0) {
            pileOfPos[p] = array[p]; //33rd line of code   
            }
        }
        System.out.println("pileOfPos: " + Arrays.toString(pileOfPos));`
```

Console:

```
pileOfNeg: [-599, -85, -17, -14, -12]

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
    at Arrays.main(Arrays.java:33)
```

Answer (score 3):

You are checking against `array`'s `.length` field, not `piloeOfPos`'s `.length` field in your `for` loop.

```
int[] pileOfPos = new int[array.length - 7];
for (int p = 0; p < array.length; p++) {
```

... needs to become ...

```
int[] pileOfPos = new int[array.length - 7];
for (int p = 0; p < pileOfPos.length; p++) {
```

Mind you, you are actually referencing two arrays within the loop by the single `p` index.  That means that if the situation is reversed, you will still receive an exception.  You really need to check the indexes of both individually.  In other words, you can't loop through the elements of one of the arrays and simply *assume* that the others have the same lengths.

Comment: ... and obviously the same for `pileOfNeg`

Comment: @PM77-1 This is true.

Comment: @asteri Replacing p < array.length with p < pileOfPos.length fills pileOfPos with zeros. What do you mean by "referencing two arrays within the loop by the single p index"? Btw, thanks for trying to help.

Comment: @Vicky Yeah, my answer wasn't meant to fix your program's functionality.  Just to address the Exception which you posted.  What I meant is that you are really looping over the elements of both `array` and `pileOfPos` within the same loop and with the same variable (`p`).  That's bad, because the `p` is bounded by the length of only *one* of the arrays.  So you're just assuming that the other will have an element at the same index, and that's not a safe/valid assumption to make.

Answer (score 0):

you have 8 positive integers but you are initializing your pileOfPos array to be of size 6. Either fix it by doing it like this:
`int[] pileOfPos = new int[array.length - 5];`

or better

`int[] pileOfPos = new int[array.length - pileOfNeg.length];`

Comment: Nope, it trows exeption again. sry. Thx for answer

Comment: well that was stupid of me, I just realized you don't count zeros as positive values. Your issue is in this line: 

`for (int p = 0; p < array.length; p++) {`

you should loop by `array.length - 1` since your piles of array has a size of 6 and you are looping from 0 to 6 which is 7 rounds.
You can fix it like this:
`for (int p = 0; p < array.length - 1; p++) {`